# how to convert java.sql.Array to an integer array

Tags: java, arrays, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Hello to everyone i'm stucked with this simple problem.

i'm trying to load an integer array from my Postgres DB.

My Code:

```
Array a = rs.getArray("my_field");

int[] b = (int[])a.getArray();
```

The Exception Displayed:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class [Ljava.lang.Integer; cannot be cast to class [I ([Ljava.lang.Integer; and [I are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
```

How can i convert java.sql.Array into an int[] array or into an arraylist?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but: Postgres 9.3 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cast it to an array of `Integer`:

```
Array a = rs.getArray("my_field");
Integer[] b = (Integer[])a.getArray();
```

Note that `a` will be `null` if the column is `null` in the database, so you should check that before calling `a.getArray()`.